# Getting Error in mounted hook: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in VUE js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am new to VUEJS and have little knowledge of state and mutations. I have a state which has a property called OSDViewer. This property of state is not being used anywhere else in app.
My state looks like following.

```
const state = {
    OSDviewer: null,
}
```

In my mutations i am trying to set this OSDViwer to an openseadragon object in following way.

```
setupOsdCanvas: (state, payload) => {
        var OSDviewer = new openseadragon.Viewer({
            id: payload,
            showNavigationControl: false,
            showNavigator: true,
            navigatorId: 'navigator',
            maxZoomPixelRatio: 2
        })
        state.OSDviewer = OSDviewer;
        state.OSDviewer.addHandler('canvas-key', e => {
            if (e.originalEvent.code === 'KeyR' || e.originalEvent.code === 'KeyF') {
                e.preventDefaultAction = true
            }
        })
    },
```

but i am getting following error

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook:
>   "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

What can i do to fix this problem and what is causing it ?
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you assigning it to `state`? The store is for holding *data*. Instantiating a third-party image viewer belongs in a component.

Comment: @skirtle i have tried instantiating the object in component and then passed this object at payload to mutation and then set the state.OSDViewer to the payload but still the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: My point was that it shouldn't be in the store's `state` at all.